# Showing that $a^2 \ge 4 b(a-b)$ when $a>b>0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Clearly $a^2 \ge b(a-b)$ but where I am getting tripped up is showing that 
$$ a^2 \ge 4 b(a-b)$$ when $a>b>0$?

That is, the multiplication by $4$ is throwing me off.

I figure I can graph the difference of the left and right side as a function of a for different values of $b$ and the result would likely be clear by inspection, but I am unsure of how or if I can show this formally?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Both $b$ and $a-b$ are positive. Further, $b + (a-b) = a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute force standard way to do this is to rearrange and complete the square to get a tautology, then observe that each step is reversible (so just work backwards to get your proof):
\begin{align*}
a^2 \geq 4b(a - b)
&\iff a^2 \geq 4ab - 4b^2 \\
&\iff a^2 - 4ab + 4b^2 \geq 0 \\
&\iff (a - 2b)^2 \geq 0
\end{align*}
The last inequality is true since $a,b \in \mathbb R$. In fact, we didn't need to assume that $a > b > 0$.